# Menubar + Commandbar on WM 5.0 and WM 6.5.3

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-mobile, toolbar, menubar

I'm developing a Windows Mobile application, and I faced a problem with `CCommandBar`, which combines toolbar and menubar. Well, I mean the following:

```
m_wndCommandBar.InsertMenuBar(IDR_MAINFRAME);
m_wndCommandBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME);
```

I have only one root menu option in my command bar and some buttons in toolbar.
It works perfectly on Windows Mobile till version 6.5.3, but on WM 6.5.3 all toolbar buttons have the same dimensions as the menu item: http://transaq.ru/cl_files/problem.png

Is it possible to force WM 6.5.3 to draw command bar the same way as WM 5.0 did? Of course, I can use only toolbar and throw away my menubar, but I want to keep the old UI.

Comment: Please can you add the image again or edit your post?

Comment: I don't work on that project anymore, so I think those images are lost.

Answer (score 1):

This brings tears in my eyes, I used to live and breathe windowsCe and it was the bleeding cutting edge.

Its a bug, send a resize msg to the form or the toolbar on form activate. I had this problem in vb.net for but we used the native sendMessage to resize it.

Unfortunatly I don't have the code anymore. But I remember that its the toolbar that is incorectly sized and just needs a resize every time it is shown.